# mod rewrite with two parameters and loading folder

Tags: htaccess, redirects, mod-rewrite

I have domain `example.com`, when someone go to this domain, I need to automatically redirect to `example.com/en/` and need `/en/` to be a parameter of variable `lang`.

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)?/?$ ?lang=$1&menu_url=$2 [L]
```

Comment: What is an example of a value of the `menu_url` parameter?   Have you tried to implement a redirect rule that redirects when you hit the base URL?

Comment: Normal url is example.com/index.php?lang=en&menu_url=contact 
It normaly works fine. But i need automaticaly load example.com/en/ instead of example.com. I tried to redirtect via RedirectMatch, but it's not working with parametr. example.com/en/ is depend on loading menu language.

It's easy, i need to disable load only example.com, i need only example.com/en/

Comment: Your question is still not clear. Redirecting to `/en/` and including `en` in the URL parameter are seemingly two different tasks. Is the directive you posted a working directive for passing the `lang` (and `menu_url`) URL parameter (although it's not strictly correct, if it is)? You need to edit your question to list examples of the URLs being requested and the desired target URL and underlying filesystem path. What URLs are you linking to in your application? For instance, what about requests for `example.com/foo`? Or are you only dealing with `example.com/`, as suggested in your question?

Answer (score 1):

Your question is not clear. However, to redirect from `example.com/` to `example.com/en/` (as stated in your question) then you would need something like the following at the top of your `.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^$ /en/ [R,L]
```

That literally only redirects from `/` to `/en/`. However, if you have a requested URL of the form `/foo` that need to redirect to `/en/foo` then you would need something like the following instead:

```
RewriteRule !^en/ /en%{REQUEST_URI} [R,L]
```

I assume you are already linking to `/en/...` in your application and that you are using Apache 2.4 (as opposed to 2.2) - otherwise the above directives may not work correctly.

> ```
> RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)?/?$ ?lang=$1&menu_url=$2 [L]
> ```

Then your existing directive (above) would rewrite the request to include the `lang` URL parameter. However, this is not strictly. If you are intending to rewrite the request to `index.php` (as mentioned in your comment), then you should explicitly include this inthe *substitution* string, instead of reply on mod_dir to issue an additional subrequest for the directory index. In other words:

```
 RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)?/?$ index.php?lang=$1&menu_url=$2 [L]
```

Comment: Thanks for answer, finally i use part of your sentence and think, how to do. In the end, i used php header with requirement and it's absolutely, what i want and what i find.